# Bluetooth not working on 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm using ubuntu14.04 and the bluetooth on it is not working the bluetooth shows "no bluetooth adapters found". My device is RaLink 3290

Comment: realtek drivers can be tricky with Ubuntu.  Have you visited the realtek site?